# debugging/break in one process doesn't stop the other ones after VS2012 installed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

recently I've installed VS2012

I have an application that is a socket server and run another client application to hit it.

before installing vs2012 when I was debugging everything was stopping, but now other threads keep on going.

I checked the Debug Options and "Break all processes when one process breaks" is ticked

I also tried using VS2010 but same problem